# which set command to display entire line in sql output to txt file

Tags: sql, oracle, set, output, spool

I am trying to output a query result to a txt file in Windows.  The query is being executed in Oracle.  I want to export the entire record one by one but gets cut off at the end, the query however displays the full line.

I thought the command:
SET linesize 2000 will do the trick but no luck:

Getting:
2702M11F13-XL   38550116-06         Test            3   325     http://www.test.com/clot

Should get (what shows in query output):
2702M11F13-XL   38550116-06         Text            3   325     http://www.test.com/clothing/outerwear/coats/test/hybridge-lite-vest/p/38550116         CAD

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay I think I figured a little bit out.  The problem is I am doing a select query with || chr(9) || in between columns so that it is tab delimited.  Is there a way I can just put that in the SET command like SET COLSEP "&TAB"?  This apparently does not work, says "CANNOT SET COLSEP".

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using `set colsep`

Refer to the [Oracle Sql*Plus documentation for `set colsep`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2698758)

Note that there's also [`set tab {on/off}`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2683445) which is used to convert tabs to spaces

Comment: I tried using the set colset and am getting the same error "Cannot set colset".  Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: sorry, it must be **colsep** of course. Please copy and paste exactly what you entered and what you got

Comment: SQL> set colsep
Cannot SET COLSEP

SQL> set colsep "&tab"
Cannot SET COLSEP

Comment: you need to use single quotes